# Identification of connector used in a plastic card printer

Tags: power, connector, identification

[image: photo of 2-pin connector attached to 2 wires]

2 position power connector (24 V) needs to be identified. 
Outside dimmentions: 7,7 x 7,2 mm. 
Pin pitch: 4,0 mm

Comment: The need for a multimeter arises.

Comment: Many connector manufacturers make several connectors which looks very similar, but are different sizes.  It would help if you could edit your post (look at the bottom, to the left of your name/photo) and add a few measurements. The pin pitch and outside dimensions would be the most useful.

Comment: Probably a JST connector, but you should measure and measure...

Comment: +1 great pic! And welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information you gave this appears to be a [JST VHR-2N](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/jst-sales-america-inc/VHR-2N/455-1183-ND/608624) - There should be a marking on the back side of the tab.

This picture is from the opposite side, however it appears to match your visual and dimensions.

[image]

Here is a link to a 360 degree image. https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/jst-sales-america-inc/VHR-2N/455-1183-ND/608624#images-2